# Control the format of the inputs when using wellPanel

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

How can the `shinydashboard` inputs be formatted when wrapped in `wellPanel` so that they look the same as without using `wellPanel`. In the image below, the input box within the `wellPanel` is indented slightly more to the right and is a different size. (I can control the size, somewhat, by manually changing the `style` but not automatically)

[image]

Code:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)

ui <- dashboardPage(
        dashboardHeader(),
        dashboardSidebar(width=500,
              sidebarMenu(id = "id1",
                    textInput("a", "AAA"),  
                     wellPanel(
                        textInput("b", "BBB")  
                     )
        )),
        dashboardBody(
            tags$head(
              tags$style(HTML('.well .shiny-input-container { width: 250px; }'))
              ))
        )

runApp(shinyApp(ui, function(input, output) {}))
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding this style argument to your well panel it should work

```
 wellPanel(style = "padding-left:0px;",
                                     textInput("b", "BBB")  
                                 )
```

example output: [image]

full code:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(width=500,
                     sidebarMenu(id = "id1",
                                 textInput("a", "AAA"),  
                                 wellPanel(style = "padding-left:0px;",
                                     textInput("b", "BBB")  
                                 )
                     )),
    dashboardBody(
        tags$head(
            tags$style(HTML('.well .shiny-input-container { width: 250px; 
            
            
            }
                            
                            
                            
                            '))
        ))
)

runApp(shinyApp(ui, function(input, output) {}))
```

Comment: Great, thanks Irfan. Do you know if there is a way to inherit all of the CSS so that the other settings are the same, size etc. Or do you know where i can find the setting -- I had no luck when viewing the page source

Comment: I dont know about inheriting from the other input, however you can set the size of the textinput  field yourself by adding the CSS into the  tags$style(HTML()), the tag would simply be the id of the input so adding #b{width:400px;} would set the width to 400px, hope this helps